# Sort observable array of objects

Tags: typescript, rxjs, angular8

Do we have ay observable operators in place to do the magic of ordering objects based on property.
Like below.

```js
Obs$ =[{ "id ":4 , "name": "sss"},{ "id ":48 , "name":"aaa"},{ "id ":14 , "name":"ccc"} ]
```

To sort based on name, I can do this using javascript sort method with the help of compare function. It would be helpful if we have any rxjs way to achieve this.

Comment: There is no sort operator in rxjs

Answer (score 4):

I guess this code would work just fine for you.
Stackblitz example available [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-bt3lqw).

```
import { of } from 'rxjs'; 
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

const sortByName = (a, b) => {
  const nameA = a.name.toLocaleUpperCase();
  const nameB = b.name.toLocaleUpperCase();
  return (nameA < nameB) ? -1 : (nameA > nameB) ? 1 : 0;
}

const $observable = of([
  { "id ": 4,  "name": "sss" },
  { "id ": 48, "name": "aaa" },
  { "id ": 14, "name": "ccc" }
]);

$observable
  .pipe(map(data => data.sort(sortByName)))
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: As I said earlier iam looking for rxjs specifically.this is normal javascript comparison .you can use localecompare also rather than this.

Comment: There is no such operator in RxJS. You can create a custom operator if you want, even though I think it's not relevant. Why do you absolutely want it to be done with RxJS ?